# Validate minimum and maximum length for separate cases in one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I validate a surname field like this

```
  validates :surname,
    :presence       => true,
    :length         => { :within => min_surname_length..max_surname_length, :message => "is bad (minimum is #{min_surname_length}, maximum is  is #{max_surname_length})" }
```

but I would like to separate cases when minimum and maximum without separate syntax validation like this

```
validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 3
validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 30
```

In few words, I would like to do something like this (I know, it is wrong):

```
  validates :surname,
    :presence       => true,
    :length         => { :within => min_surname_length..max_surname_length, 
                         :message => "is bad (minimum is #{min_surname_length}" IF MINIMUM, 
                         :message => "is bad (maximum is  is #{max_surname_length})" IF MAXIMUM }
```

**How it is possible to do that in one time?**

---

**SOLUTION**

This is how I will use it:

```
validates :surname,
    :length         => { :within => min_password_length..max_password_length,
                        :too_short => 'too short message',
                        :too_long => 'too long message' }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
validates_length_of :surname,
  :within => 3..30,
  :too_short => 'too short message',
  :too_long => 'too long message'
```

Comment: Can you tell me. I just want t string is longer than 3. doesn't need shorter than 30. what should I do. Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt, use `:minimum => 3` instead of `within => 3..30`.  `:too_short` will still work, and `:too_long` will, or course, no longer be necessary so you can remove it